# Taylor Series with (x-a) and delta x

Tags: taylor-expansion

There are two different ways to write a Taylor series function according to Wikipedia and other websites (https://www.uni-muenster.de/Physik.TP/archive/fileadmin/lehre/part2_hypebolic/node6.html):

(1):$$ f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + \Delta x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2} \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2} \;\;...$$

(2):$$ f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)f'(a) + \frac{(x-a)^2}{2}f''(a) \;\;...$$

I am confused on how these two are the same. If you let $\Delta x = x-a$ shouldn't the formula for (1) be the following:

(1):$$ f(x) = f(\Delta x + a) + \Delta x \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2} \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2} \;\;...$$

A descriptive answer would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the question here? There is often more than one way to express the same mathematical idea. Please [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking. (Don't respond in a comment, and don't ask us to follow a link.)

Comment: Hello, I have edited it. Sorry I prematurely posted it before.

Comment: You need to rename one of the $x$s. In formula (1), let $x=a$ and $\Delta x = x-a$. Also, your partial derivatives should be single-variable derivatives.

Comment: Hello Ted, so you are saying formula (1) should be this:

(1):$$ f(x + \Delta x) = f(x) + \Delta x f'(x) + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2} f''(x) \;\;...$$

Can you possibly write about the equation you are describing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The two equations are describing the same thing, but are using the variable $x$ differently. In the first form, the "centre" of the Taylor expansion is at $x$, and the expansion is in terms of the distance $\Delta x$ away from it. In the second form, the centre is at $a$, and the expansion is in terms of the distance $x - a$ away from it. So in other words we can translate between the two with the mapping:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ \Delta x \end{pmatrix} \longleftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a \\ x - a \end{pmatrix} $$

It might be a bit easier to see if we rename the first $x$ to $x_0$, so we can just explicitly state that $x_0 = a$ and $x - x_0 = \Delta x$, so we have:

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(x_0 + \Delta x) & = & f(x_0) + \Delta x f'(x_0) + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2} f''(x_0) + \ldots \\
& = & f(x_0) + (x - x_0) f'(x_0) + \frac{(x - x_0)^2}{2} f''(x_0) + \ldots \\
& = & f(a) + (x - a) f'(x_0) + \frac{(x - a)^2}{2} f''(x_0) + \ldots \\
& = & f(x) \end{eqnarray}$$

Your first example is maybe being a little obtuse in its notation because (a) it's using partial derivatives $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ even though the function in question is univariate, and (b) it's not making it very clear that $\frac{df}{dx}$ is the derivative of $f$, with respect to the *variable* $x$, evaluated at the *value* $x$.

Comment: Hello ConMan, Thanks so much for the answer! After reading it through it's starting to make a little more sense. So would it be correct to rewrite equation (1) as the following to be more explicit:

$$ f(x+\Delta x) = f(x) + \Delta x \frac{df}{dx}\bigg|_x + \frac{\Delta x^2}{2} \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}\bigg|_x \;\;...$$

Comment: You could do that. Generally, as long as it's clear what the notation is trying to do it's fine, so even $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ probably gets the notion across.

Comment: Ok sure, thanks a lot! Like you said it's basically just two ways of thinking about it. The first form is taking the center at x and expanding around $\Delta x$ away from it while the second form is taking the center at a and expanding x-a away from it.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing (1) and (2) in
\begin{align*}
f(x + \Delta x) &= \color{blue}{f(x)} + \color{blue}{\Delta x} f^{\prime}(x) + \frac{\left(\Delta x\right)^2}{2} f^{\prime\prime}(x)+\cdots\tag{1}\\
f(x) &= \color{blue}{f(a)} + \color{blue}{(x-a)} f^{\prime}(a) + \frac{(x-a)^2}{2} f^{\prime\prime}(a)+\cdots\tag{2}\\
\end{align*}
we have

- in (1) a Taylor series in $x+\Delta x$ evaluated at $x$,
- in (2) a Taylor series in $x$ evaluated at $a$.

Your substitution $\Delta x\to x-a$ is fine. But we also have to respect that the center of the Taylor series has been changed from $x$ to $a$. We therefore consider the substitutions
\begin{align*}
\Delta x&\to x-a\\
x&\to a
\end{align*}
Putting them into (1) we obtain (2), since
\begin{align*}
f(x+\Delta x)&\to \color{blue}{f(a+(x-a))}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{=f(x)}
\color{blue}{=f(a)+(x-a)f^{\prime}(a) + \frac{(x-a)^2}{2} f^{\prime\prime}(a)+\cdots}
\end{align*}